# Android Api for Skype?

Tags: android, api, skype

I wonder is there any Skype API for Android. What I wanted to do was actually access Skype contacts using API and display in my application against every user. So is there an Android API for Skype?

From the internet I know this about skype API.
Skype provide two APIs for developer on the Skype developer site

- Skype KIT Beta
- Accessories (Public API)

On the Developer forum clearly written that Skype KIT Beta is not for Mobile device.

Here is reference https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10630/Can-I-use-SkypeKit-to-develop-applications-for-mobile-devices?fromSearchFirstPage=false

Then I tried to learn about the Public API. But on the documentation page that’s defined about Public API.

The API has two layers:

- Communication Layer - is a set of methods for external application to establish connection to Skype client and communicate with it.
- Command Protocol Layer - is a text-based "language" that external applications can use to speak to the Skype client, once communication channel is established by Communication Layer.

Additionally, there are several Skype API wrapper libraries that encapsulate the functionality of Skype API. Such wrappers can act as optional third layers.

Communication layer API required Skype client always run on the system, that’s why it seems to be for Computer OS (windows ,mac) not for mobile.

In the wrapper API there is "Skype4Java - Java wrapper." It gave me the Hope, but the problem is to access this, I need to longing to Skype developer site and I tried to login with my Skype ID and got the error "this Skype name has no access", I don’t know what access to required.

Could someone help me how to get access into developer site (how to do login) which access rights are required and any other API which help to get Skype Contacts and their status on Android. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can have access to the PUBLIC API documentation here http://developer.skype.com/accessories

Comment: I did this myself and I have a solution that does work on some devices, but does not on some others. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61438438/how-to-obtain-skype-id-from-contact-db-on-android-my-solution-is-almost-ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current public API has no methods for Android.

You should sign up for SkypeKit for this here:

http://developer.skype.com/skypekit

Comment: Thanks showHide, but do you think SkypeKit help  to develop application for Android, because i don't want to spend extra time if its not possible by skypekit. what do you say about this?

Comment: @IjazAhmed plz help me...i don't know how to integrate skype in android....i want to get user's status and also user's profile in my app.please help me

Comment: SkypeKit is no longer supported - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12322/is-skypekit-being-discontinued

Comment: Does the Skype Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Answer (score 2):

Some people managed to use SkypeKit on their android.
However it is currently not allowed by the license and you would need to build different apks for different devices.