# How to use Skype Java API inside android application?

Tags: java, android, skype4java

I want to make one application that will monitor chat history of other IM in phone.

I couldn't find any Skype API for Android, although I found Skype4Java API from net. I wish to use this in an Android application. I have imported the .jar file of that API to my Java build path. When I run my code, I am getting errors for libskype.jnilib and libskype.so file.
I also can't delete that file also, because when I attempt to delete that I get an error. Please tell how to do that?

How can I use Skype's Java API inside an Android app?

Comment: This link may be useful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044512/android-api-for-skype

Comment: What is the exception do you get in Logcat? Please send me your logcat.

Comment: The library 'SkypeInJava-1.0.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
 The following libraries were found:
 libskype.jnilib
 libskype.so

Answer (score 0):

As of the current writing of this answer, there is no Android implementation of Skype. There are numerous third-party chat APIs, although I personally can't name one since I haven't worked with any.

The reason why the Skype4Java API is throwing errors at you is because it was not designed for use with Android. To delete the .jar file, you must remove all references to it and remove it from your build path for attempting a delete.