# Get Skype name from Contacts list

Tags: android, skype

I'm getting skype contacts in my android device with this code:

```
private void getContactList() {
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
                    RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
                    RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE },
            RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
            new String[] { "com.skype.contacts.sync" }, null);

    int contactNameColumn = c
            .getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE);
    int count = c.getCount();
    skypeName = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        skypeName[i] = c.getString(contactNameColumn);

        Log.i("KEY", skypeName[i]);
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but it returns the skype display names.However is there any possibility to get *Skype name* not the display name so I can call or video call using that *Skype name*?.
Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: @ChristopherSouvey Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query over the `Data` table not `RawContacts`, the `Data` table's data is organized by `mimetype`s, you just need to find the `mimetype` containing the info you're looking for, in `skype`'s case it's: `"vnd.android.cursor.item/com.skype.android.skypecall.action"`

```
private void getContactList() {
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DATA1 },
            Data.MIMETYPE + "= ?", 
            new String[] { "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.skype.android.skypecall.action" },
            null);

    while (c != null && c.moveToNext()) {
        String contact = c.getLong(0);
        String skype = c.getString(1);

        Log.i("contact " + contact + " has skype username: " + skype);
    }
}
```

- I've typed the code here, so it's not checked and I might have typos
- Make sure you ALWAYS close cursors via `c.close()`

Comment: Hello marmor again, I would like to get skype user photo, it is possible in the same way ?.
Thanks @marmor

Comment: Does the Skype Android SDK support allowing the SDP portion of the message to be modified, such that the media RTP streams will be routed to a different IP address and port than what the application is running on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not incredibly familiar with the Android-Skype API, but it looks like this line

```
.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_ALTERNATIVE);
```

is what pulls the display name instead of the username. You could check the API and see if there's another RawContacts.*method* that fetches the username instead.

Additional information could be available here:

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/skype

or

http://www.skype.com/en/developer/

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I tried the other methods, there isn't something related with username...
And about the Skype API, I search I figure it out that no public API. And according to many link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044512/android-api-for-skype
They don't have API for android.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood your original post. You are running this code through a terminal emulator on your android device?

Comment: I'm running this from android device.